# How to use/setup TexturePacker2 libgdx

Tags: animation, graphics, libgdx

I have a difficulty with `texturepacker2` from `libgdx`. I was trying to create `textureAtlas` using texturepakcer2 so that I can create animated images. However I could not use

TexturePacker2.process(Input Directory Path", "Output Directory Path", "texture_file");

Because it could not recognize TexturePacker2.
Even thought I import `gdx-tool.jar` file inside `libs` and also added libraries through 
`Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add jars`, it still cannot resolve nor recognize the `gdx-tool.jar`.

How can I create texture atlas using `TexturePakcer2`? I heard there is a way to create using nightly-build from `libgdx`, how can I do it? When I unzip latest nightly-build there were so many jar, but I could only run setup-ui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways. I used to take the way of implementing it into my Desktop application. Whenever i start it, the Atlas is generated. (If i changed something in it).

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.title = "MyApp";
        cfg.useGL20 = true; 
        cfg.fullscreen = false; 
        // switch for fullscreen
        if (cfg.fullscreen)
        {
            cfg.width = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width;
            cfg.height = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height;
        }
        else
        {
            cfg.width = 1280;
            cfg.height = 720;
        }

        cfg.addIcon("data/appiconWindows.png", FileType.Internal); 
        // automatic packing of the textures and images and so on
        Settings settings = new Settings();
        settings.maxWidth = 2048;
        settings.maxHeight = 2048;
        settings.paddingX = 0;
        settings.paddingY = 0;
        TexturePacker2.process(settings, "directory with the files",
                "output dir", "name of Atlas"); //third is outputdir
        new LwjglApplication(new MainClass(), cfg);
    }
}
```

Dont forget to add the tools lib to the Desktop project. `gdx-tools.jar` From the nightly or the Stable.

Else you can call it with the console. Like this:

```
java -cp gdx.jar;extensions/gdx-tools/gdx-tools.jar com.badlogic.gdx.tools.texturepacker.TexturePacker inputDir [outputDir] [packFileName]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `TexturePacker` from `com.badlogic.gdx.tools.imagepacker.TexturePacker` then create a class as below:

```
public class TextureSetup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //TexturePacker; using default settings
        TexturePacker.Settings packSettings = new TexturePacker.Settings();     

        TexturePacker.process(packSettings, "input-folder", "output-folder", "textures.pack");
    }
}
```