# <LibGDX> How do I load multiple textures from the same file?

Tags: java, libgdx

How do I load multiple textures from the same file?

I'm learning `LibGDX` and I don't know how this process is named.

I have a file that contains all the textures I need. Is it possible to load textures by selecting regions on the same file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look this ->
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer

I think what you are looking for is the textureAtlas the link also talks about that and can look elsewhere.

I do not use gui for texturePacket, but maybe this this is to your liking

http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/category/desktop-applications/libgdx-texturepacker-gui/

Also, on the other hand:
[How to use/setup TexturePacker2 libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21820974/how-to-use-setup-texturepacker2-libgdx)

I hope help

perhaps also want to look at this ->
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-

Comment: Sorry but, the last link isn't working, can you update it please?

Comment: @TheL0w3R I just checked, the four link, and run.